# Create MySQL table with Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create a MySQL table, I run this:

```
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Library (Words, String);");
```

But I get the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
>       MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' String)' at line 1

Comment: What is `(Words, String)` supposed to be? Two columns? Or one column of a type "String"? Because it is the wrong syntax for either

Comment: You need to specify the type of the column, e.g Words varchar(200). A table should also have an identifier column, and String shouldn't be used as its a  keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you are using is incorrect, you should define the columns and their data types, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Library (Words varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL);
```

It means that will create the `Library` table with the column `Words`. You can try to use that syntax in your statement, for example:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Library (Words varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL)";
statement.executeUpdate(createTable);
```